# Can we use foreach inside of a map in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I have a RDD[(String, List[String])]

I would like to loop through the List inside RDD for each record.
Is it possible?

```
RDD has this data
(4,List(5, 6, 7, 1, 3))
(8,List(9, 5, 7))
(5,List(8, 9, 6, 4))
(9,List(5, 10, 8))
(1,List(4, 3))
(6,List(5, 4, 2, 3, 10))
(2,List(3, 6))
(7,List(10, 8, 4))
(3,List(4, 6, 1, 2))
(10,List(6, 7, 9))
```

I would like to get 2-hop projections of keys in this list. For each element in the value list should be attached with its own list from the RDD.

Resultant RDD for **first list item** should be

```
(4,List((5,List(8, 9, 6, 4)), (6,List(5, 4, 2, 3, 10)), (7,List(10, 8, 4)), (1,List(4, 3)), (3,List(4, 6, 1, 2))))
```

Here (5,List(8, 9, 6, 4) is inturn taken from the RDD

Similarly for all the records

Comment: _"Is it possible"_ - yeah, why not? Have you tried it? did you get an error? If so, which error? or maybe you it didn't produce and error but neither the expected behavior, if so, what was that expected behavior and what really happened? Can you give us a **MCVE**?

Comment: it's a bad practise. Because RDD designed for data processing but `foreach` is not for data processing. It's mostly for side effects. For what purposes you are going to use foreach?

Comment: I do not understand the expected output nor the explanation of the processing that you want to do... but in any case, if you want to transform something you use `map` not `foreach`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have updated my question.

Comment: @BorisAzanov Updated Question

Comment: @suraj13k you would need to `faltten` your **RDD** then do a `cartesian` product with itself and finally a `groupByKey`. But that seems very complex. Try to see if you can model your problem differently.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Okay Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to achieve this by using nested map. Hence I thought of posting my answer.

```
myRDD.map({case (node,p1Array) => (node, p1Array.map(k => myRDDArray.filter(y=> y._1 == k)(0)))})
```

Result:

```
(8,List((9,List(5, 10, 8)), (5,List(8, 9, 4, 6)), (7,List(10, 8, 4))))
(4,List((7,List(10, 8, 4)), (1,List(4, 3)), (3,List(1, 2, 4, 6)), (5,List(8, 9, 4, 6)), (6,List(10, 5, 4, 2, 3))))
(5,List((6,List(10, 5, 4, 2, 3)), (8,List(9, 5, 7)), (9,List(5, 10, 8)), (4,List(7, 1, 3, 5, 6))))
(9,List((5,List(8, 9, 4, 6)), (10,List(6, 7, 9)), (8,List(9, 5, 7))))
(1,List((4,List(7, 1, 3, 5, 6)), (3,List(1, 2, 4, 6))))
(6,List((10,List(6, 7, 9)), (5,List(8, 9, 4, 6)), (4,List(7, 1, 3, 5, 6)), (2,List(3, 6)), (3,List(1, 2, 4, 6))))
(2,List((3,List(1, 2, 4, 6)), (6,List(10, 5, 4, 2, 3))))
(7,List((10,List(6, 7, 9)), (8,List(9, 5, 7)), (4,List(7, 1, 3, 5, 6))))
(3,List((4,List(7, 1, 3, 5, 6)), (6,List(10, 5, 4, 2, 3)), (1,List(4, 3)), (2,List(3, 6))))
(10,List((6,List(10, 5, 4, 2, 3)), (7,List(10, 8, 4)), (9,List(5, 10, 8))))
```